# How to output array in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to implement the matrix multiplication as provided by in [Scala for Java](http://blog.scala4java.com/2011/12/matrix-multiplication-in-scala-single.html) but I'm having trouble showing the arrays.

When trying, for example,

```
println(singleThreadedMultiplication2(Seq(Array(1, 2),
                                          Array(2, 3)),
                                          Array(Array(11, 8),
                                                Array(2, 6))))
```

it will show `[[I@2c79a2e7`. How can I show the contents of the array?

Comment: This is a bizarre value... Its type is weird 'cause you've mixed `Array[Int]` with `Array[Array[Int]]` within the `Seq`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given Array foo you can do:

```
println(foo.mkString(","))
```

One little note of *why* is it so: Array, unlike Seq or most other classes do not overload .toString method, so [Object.toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) will be used.

EDIT:

Looks like in your code (it depends on the type of singleThreadedMultiplication2 result) you have to write:

```
val result = singleThreadedMultiplication2(
                     Seq(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 3)), 
                     Array(Array(11, 8), Array(2, 6))
             )

println(result
          .map(_.mkString("[",",","]")) // making every inner array readable
          .mkString(",")                // now making outer array
       )
```

To correctly output result.

Comment: When I tried that I received the same result as before only now `[I@65b60280, [I@105e55ab`

Comment: @chrisportelli singleThreadedMultiplication2 returns array of arrays?

Comment: Yes, it returns an array of integer arrays - `Array[Array[Int]]`

Comment: Array is a special JVM construct, so there is no chance it will change in a newer Scala version. It will probably never change, because it depends on JVM only and they want 100% backward compatibility.